# Java Reading txt custom methods

Tags: java

I was working on a project that can translate a simple language.This language translates simple commands like `print(hello)` in to `System.out.println("hello");` line by line in a .txt file. the template goes like this:

```
setup()
{
   print(hello);
}    
setup()
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how this could work?

Comment: please show your effort. read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Some key words you can start looking for or Google for `parsing`, `scripting`, `scripting in java`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, splitting the problem in parts helps a lot. In your case, there are three main steps:

1. Read the input from the file
2. Translate it to java code
3. Write it to another file

There are so many tutorials and websites about java, so you can use a searching engine and find tutorials which help you.